# DataFrame group returning regular dafaframe

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I am trying to group by on a column on a dataframe and return a a regular dataframe (Much like you would get from SQL. But when I try, it gives me a slightly different structure.

```
data = [['tom', 10], ['nick', 15], ['juli', 14], ['tom', 5], ['nick', 10], ['jack', 10]] 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'Score'])


   Surname  Score
0   tom     10
1   nick    15
2   July    14
3   tom      5
4   nick    10
5   Jack    10
```

This is the output I want to get

```
   Surname  Total_score
0   tom     15
1   nick    25
2   July    14
3   Jack    10
```

But when I try

```
df.groupby('Name').Score.agg(['sum'])
```

The result kinda comes out like

```
            sum
 Surname    
0   tom     15
1   nick    25
2   July    14
3   Jack    10
```

Comment: add a `reset_index()` in the end: `df.groupby('Name').Score.agg(['sum']).reset_index()`

Comment: Oh great! Can I rename 'sum'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```py
df.groupby("Name", as_index=False).agg({"Score": sum}).rename(columns={"Score": "Total_score"})
```

Output:

```py
   Name  Total_score
0  jack           10
1  juli           14
2  nick           25
3   tom           15
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data = [['tom', 10], ['nick', 15], ['juli', 14], ['tom', 5], ['nick', 10], ['jack', 10]] 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'Score'])


   Name  Score
0   tom     10
1  nick     15
2  juli     14
3   tom      5
4  nick     10
5  jack     10
```

we can summarise the df by below action:

```
df1 = df.groupby('Name').agg({'Score':"sum"}).reset_index()

df1
   Name  Score
0  jack     10
1  juli     14
2  nick     25
3   tom     15
```